# macros and actionscript3

Tags: flash, actionscript, macros, preprocessor, flash-builder

This might be a trivial question but I didn't find a definite answer for it. Anyways is there a way to use macros, or to be more specific, function macros (for example `#define test(x) #x`in C) in actionscript3? Or is that something that is not possible with that language?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the html-template files?

${project}
The name of the project, e.g. MyProject.

${application}
The name of the application, e.g. MyApp.

${version_major}
The major version number of the version of Flash that is required to run this app, e.g. 9 for version 9.0 r28. You can change this and the other ${version_...} macros by going to Project > Properties, then "Flex Compiler" or "ActionScript Compiler," and then changing the player version number in the "HTML wrapper" section.

${version_minor}
The minor version number of the version of Flash that is required to run this app, e.g. 0 for version 9.0 r28.

${version_revision}
The revision number of the version of Flash that is required to run this app, e.g. 28 for version 9.0 r28.

${build_suffix}
This is equal to "-debug" when building the debug version of the SWF, and "" when building the release version.

${swf}
The name of the SWF, not including the .swf extension, e.g. MyApp or MyApp-debug. This is essentially a convenience macro which is equivalent to ${application}${build_suffix}.

${bgcolor}
The background color of the application, as specified in the backgroundColor attribute of the  tag, or, in the case of ActionScript-only projects, in the backgroundColor field of the [SWF] metadata attribute of the main application class, e.g. [SWF(backgroundColor="#ffffff")] public class MyApp extends Sprite (see this post for more information on setting the width, height, and background color of an ActionScript project). The result is in the form #rrggbb, e.g. #ffffff. This can actually be a little tricky to use, because by default, the background of a Flex app is actually a gentle gradient from one color to another; if you want the HTML background to match the background of your Flex app, you may need to fiddle with both the backgroundColor and backgroundGradientColors attributes of the  tag.

${width}
The width of the application, as specified in the width attribute of the  tag, or, in the case of ActionScript-only projects, in the width field of the [SWF] metadata attribute of the main application class, e.g. [SWF(width="300", height="400")] public class MyApp extends Sprite.

${height}
The height of the application, as specified in the height attribute of the  tag, or, in the case of ActionScript-only projects, in the height field of the [SWF] metadata attribute of the main application class, e.g. [SWF(width="300", height="400")] public class MyApp extends Sprite.

${title}
The title of the application, as specified in the pageTitle attribute of the  tag, or, in the case of ActionScript-only projects, in the pageTitle field of the [SWF] metadata attribute of the main application class, e.g. [SWF(pageTitle="flex r00lz")] public class MyApp extends Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean pre-processor macros, no.  ActionScript does not support them.

Comment: That's a shame? Is there anything available that substitutes them?

Comment: The best alternative you're like to find is an IDE plug-in that does code substitution before passing code to the ActionScript compiler.  I do not know of one off-hand though.  ActionScript 3 was set up to make it unappetizing to put things in truly global scope.  The best way around it, in my opinion, is to create a class called Constants that has many static members.  Import it and invoke the static members instead of using macros (such as Constants.test(), Constants.MY_CONSTANT, etc).

Comment: I would steer clear of a fat class with globally accessible values and methods for the same reason I would steer clear of putting things in global scope in the first place.  It may have worked fine in C but AS3 is a very different language.  ... That said, do what you gotta do.

Comment: Yea I think I will just not use macros. It's not a requirement for the app I am writing but it could have made my code a little bit more readable. Oh well...

Thanks anyways guys